# Связывание таблиц в Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, связывание-данных

Помогите разобраться в связывании таблиц в Postgresql (один ко многим). Есть несколько помещений, в каждом из которых установлен электросчетчик. Необходимо таблицу с помещениями связать с таблицей, где находятся переданные показания всех счетчиков (передаются ежемесячно на протяжении длительного времени).
Связывыю внешним ключом `meter` из таблицы `places` с полем `meter_number` в таблице `meters`.

а) таблица с помещениями:

```
CREATE TABLE places (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    meter integer NOT NULL
);
```

б) таблица с показаниями счетчиков:

```
CREATE TABLE meters (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    meter_number integer NOT NULL,
    data integer NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (id, meter_number)
);
```

Внешний ключ будет ссылаться на поле `meter_number`, но это поле не уникально (т.к. в таблице meters показания по каждому счётчику за большой интервал времени), поэтому делаю уникальность для группы столбцов (`id` и `meter_number`).

в) делаю связь между таблицами:

```
ALTER TABLE places
ADD CONSTRAINT meters FOREIGN KEY (meter)
REFERENCES meters (meter_number) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Получаю ошибку:
`«ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "meters" SQL-состояние: 42830»`

Подскажите, что делаю не так? Может вообще нужно было делать таблицу с показаниями счётчиков в другом виде (один счётчик – одна таблица)? Но вроде и так должно работать, просто у меня пока не получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, нелогично, что помещение ссылается на счетчик, должно быть наоборот. Ведь в принципе, в одном помещении может быть несколько счетчиков, а вот один счетчик не может находится в нескольких помещениях. Сейчас у вас структура позволяет такое.

Во-вторых, нужно разделить счетчики и показания счетчиков в отдельные таблицы.

Итого имеем:

```
CREATE TABLE place (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name text
);

CREATE TABLE meter (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    place_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES place (id)
);

CREATE TABLE meter_data (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    meter_id integer NOT NULL  REFERENCES meter(id),
    data integer NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Разобрался и всё заработало!!!